# Matplotlib tick labels are not being set properly in jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to generate some matplotlib figures, but I'm running into issues visualizing the x/y tick labels.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 10), np.linspace(0, 10))
```

[image]

This problem only occurs within a jupyter notebook - I'm able to get this working in the ipython console so I'm wondering if there is a jupyter misconfiguration).

```
matplotlib       : 3.2.2
numpy            : 1.18.1
jupyter core     : 4.6.3
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
qtconsole        : 4.7.3
ipython          : 7.13.0
ipykernel        : 5.2.1
jupyter client   : 6.1.3
jupyter lab      : not installed
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.6
traitlets        : 4.3.3
```

EDIT: If I can get a workaround by using seaborn to load another style via `seaborn.set()`
[image]

It's curious how this got overloaded in the first place.

Comment: Did you try `plt.tight_layout()`? Maybe the figure padding is so small that labels are hidden. (It could be set that way for plots that don't have ticklabels).

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter simply returns the Matplotlib figure, so I doubt that it would be a Jupyter misconfig.

However, what you could try doing is `plt.xticks` and `plt.yticks` which manually add the ticks in. You pass one parameter, which is an array of the ticks that you want to display. In this case you would pass it like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 10), np.linspace(0, 10))
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 10, 1)) # Here np.arange() generates a sequence of number starting from 0 and ending at 10, going up in increments of 1.
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 10, 1)) # Same for the y axis

plt.show()
```

Two points of note here. Firstly, the `%matplotlib inline` in line 3 is **only necessary for when you are in a Jupyter environment**, as this is a special signal to the Jupyter kernel to display any plots inside the notebook.

Also, it is probably **good practice to have `plt.show()` at the end**, because if, in some case, you are not working in a Jupyter environment, the code will not return the plot unless you call this function. Jupyter is nice and extracts the plot, but just as good practice, use this line of code at the end.